# Soundproofing wooden server cabinet

Tags: cabinets, sound-proofing

I have build a wooden (well, 22mm mdf) cabinet to hold my server, switch etcetera. I wish to soundproof the cabinet as well as possible. Obviously complete proofing is not possible, because it needs to be ventilated quite well.
Regarding isolation, I'm torn between something fluffy like rockwool, or something more substantial like [SilentWall](https://www.recticelinsulation.com/en-gb/silentwall) (which is made of compressed shredded mattresses).
The sound I want to block is the typical server whine of the fans and hard drives. I have 50-60 mm of room on all sides to fill with isolation. What would be best? Research mostly shows up thermal isolation properties.

Comment: Any chance of water cooling? That would obviate the need for airflow in/out.

Comment: This (closed) question at serverfault has multiple suggestions, including my approach. Though in hindsight (and if possible, which it wasn't for my case) just getting a server more suited to life **not** in a server room without people is really the better option. https://serverfault.com/questions/96907/noise-damping-for-rackmount-servers-on-the-cheap/96970#96970

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'll keep the option in mind for a next project, but in this case water cooling is not a viable solution. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Ecnerwal thanks. Looks like some good info there. I didn't have a choice in server here, it has to be a hp proliant dl380. It doesn't make a huge amount of noise, most of the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More density is better, but the most critical aspect is sealing. Noise in that frequency will escape through any gaps and reverberate off nearby surfaces.

Material with more density will help with lower frequencies, which are less dependent on gaps in the enclosure for propagation. You could use about anything. Look into fiberboard wall sheathing. Any heavyish, porous material will absorb a lot of sound.